# Splitting a list<string> item and formatting it out

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, stringbuilder

I have a List that is being filled with something like this in a loop:

```
myList.Add("john,smith,50,actor");
```

Obviously I just wrote the pure string, they are actually some variables. Now what I want to do is to export this to a text file using Stringbuilder and StringWriter which I think I can manage it (already did similar things).

So I want my textfile to look like this:

```
NAME    SURNAME      AGE      WORK
john    smith        50       actor
```

And so on. Can you help me figure out a foreach loop for this case?

Comment: the codes below are true, but adding "-" is not nice, you should insert between splitted string "tab"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const string Format = "{0,-10} {1,-10} {2,-10} {3,-10}";

var myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("john,smithhh,50,actor");
myList.Add("a,b,c,d");

var res = myList.Select(i => i.Split(','));

Console.WriteLine(Format, "NAME", "SURNAME", "AGE", "WORK");
foreach (var line in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Format, line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]);
}
```

Output:

```
NAME       SURNAME    AGE        WORK
john       smithhh    50         actor
a          b          c          d
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split them into strings like this:

```
String[] strings = myList[i].Split(',');
```

And then get them individually like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++)
{
    file.Write(strings[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how can create a text file our or your `List<string>`:

```
var path = @"C:\test.txt";
var streamWriter = File.Exists(path) ? File.AppendText(path) : File.CreateText(path);
using (streamWriter)
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("NAME\tSURNAME\tAGE\tWORK");
    foreach (string s in myList)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(s.Replace(",", "\t"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you already have separator(","), so you can directly do the following for better performance, no need to convert:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
result.AppendLine("NAME\tSURNAME\tAGE\tWORK");
myList.ForEach(i => result.AppendLine(i.Replace(",", "\t")));
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("foo.txt", result.ToString());
```